# Нет выбора файлов формата docx

Tags: html, html5

Сделал инпут, в нем те файлы которые можно прикреплять,но файлы формата docx ,просто нет, в чем тут может быть дело?

```
`<input type="file" name="files" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/pdf,image/gif">`
```

Comment: Так а та машина, где Вы это проверяете, вообще в курсе, что существует такой тип файлов `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`, и что он соответствует расширению `docx`?

Comment: Да, вкурсе точно

Comment: Тогда это странно, потому что у меня приведенный Вами код вполне показывает docx-файлы в диалоге выбора файла.

Comment: попробуйте сначала разрешить только .docx файлы.
Вообще в диалоге выбора файлов, должен отображаться любой тип файла. А вот что будет загружено, уже определяется кодом